# Output of following program

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int k)
{
    if(k<10)
            printf("%d ",main(k+1));
    return k;
}
```

output is:

> 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

In arguments of `main()` function, its `argc` but how is it used here?

Comment: What is your compiler/environment, that is not a standard compliant signature for main unless your implementation specifically allows it.

Comment: Ooh..I am sorry..I forgot to mention that..its GCC

Comment: The numbers of parameters you pass to the program code will determine the initial value of k. Without passing any parameter, the initial value of k will be 1. The recursive calling to main doesn't use main the same way the O/S passes parameter to main. It calls itself just like any regular function where it passes an int argument of k+1. The recursion happens as a parameter to printf thus printf will wait for the call to main to return before it can print. The result is a reverse print order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used main function as a recursive function thus when you call it with argument 1 it will stack main function while k reach the value of 10, then it dequeue the stack and print values by reverse order. you pass ,2,3,..10 and after dequeue of stack it will print 10,9,..2

Comment: Actually when the program code is called without any argument, k will be 1 because arrgv[0] is the name of the program, thus k (which was argc) is 1. The more parameters you pass to the program the higher value k will be and the less numbers to print. If you pass a parameter of 1 that will make argc == 2 or k in this code.

Answer (score 4):

First your signature of `main` is what standard defines it. Your compiler should give warning:

```
[Warning] 'main' takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
```

### C11: 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup:

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, **though any names may be
>   used**<sub>1</sub>,as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Now, you can give any name to `argc`and `argv`. Here `argc` is `k`. Since you are passing no parameter to `main` the value of `k` is `1` because here `argv[0]` is the name of the program. Now `k=1` is used by the program as initial value and the value

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

is printed by recursive call of `main`.

---

<sub>1. emphasis is mine.</sub>

Comment: +1 A program that is not passed an argument will have argv[0] == program name and argc == 1 which in the code is renamed k.

Comment: Your are making a likely but possibly incorrect assumption that the implementation does not define that signature to be valid.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; I quoted what standard is saying and what compiler's warning is.

Comment: It also says `or in some other implementation-defined manner.`.

Comment: @muradin; Do you wanna copy of that? :). Download this from [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.cs.dal.ca%2F~vlado%2Fpl%2FC_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf&ei=GCC_UoCAL4-aiQfm5oGQDQ&usg=AFQjCNEryn7-KUvl7UjdOYs8mc9SE1QDTA&sig2=BAUzf0N11rB5KCh7JdNUrQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aGc).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour; I removeded that contradictory word now.

Comment: @muradin [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) probably has a link to all of the draft standards available.

Comment: @haccks is it possible or copyright protected? if it's possible i will appretiate. :)

Comment: @muradin You have to pay for official standards but the drafts are freely available.

Comment: @muradin; As Shafik suggested draft is free. I provided the download link.